# VB.Net Cannot connect to local database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I keep getting the error of:

> [DBNETLIB}{ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or
>   access denied.

This is my connection string:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=dbSQL1;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Comment: I don't know how you created the connection string. But a great way to create a working connection string is to: create a new file in Windows. Change the extension to `.udl`. Open the file. Connect to your database using the dialog and test your connection. Save and close. Right click on the file and edit using a text editor. Copy the connection string.

Comment: `SQLOLEDB` is old and decrepit. A .NET application has no business using this connection string at all -- use the native ADO.NET SQL driver (`providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` in your `connectionStrings`). If you *must* use OLE DB, for whatever reason, use the modern version of the OLE DB driver, [`MSOLEDBSQL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server). I'm not sure if it's related to your connectivity problem, but LocalDB is a fairly recent feature, so it certainly won't hurt.